# Install-Package : Enabling license acceptance requires a license url

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I tried installing Angular JS Core via the package manager on Visual Studio like so:

```
PM> Install-Package AngularJS.Core
```

And I got the following Error message:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Enabling license acceptance requires a license url.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  AngularJS.Core
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

How can I get the License URL to work? I also tried installing the same using the Manage Nugget Package using the GUI. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you trying to install? You could try "Install-Package AngularJS.Core -Version 1.5.5". I just checked that Package and that package (received from https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Core/) should have the "requireLicenseAcceptance" set to false and should work.

Comment: @Sosian: Thanks. I already figured it out. I needed to add Version and Number to make it run. It's working fine now. Thanks an bunch!